# Get a list of changed files between two commits or branches

Tags: python, git, bash, shell, gitpython

I'm a Python/Git newb but I'm trying to write a script that takes two branches or commits as parameters and shows a list of changed files between the two, not all the extraneous info that comes with a regular diff.

This was accomplished in bash scripting by using

```
git diff --name-only FIRSTBRANCH...SECONDBRANCH
```

but it isn't translating as easily to Python scripting using gitpython. If anyone has any idea how to do this, that'd be great.

edit: heres some code

```
user = str(sys.argv[1])
password = str(sys.argv[2])
currentBranch = str(sys.argv[3])
compBranch = str(sys.argv[4])

repo = Repo(directory)
currentCommit = repo.commit(currentBranch)
compCommit = repo.commit(compBranch)
diffed = repo.diff(currentBranch, compBranch)
```

print diff will return all the diff details when I only want a list of changed files

Comment: @MattDMo I've tried using the gitpython .diff feature, but it doesn't have a way for me to add the "--name-only" flag as far as I can tell, which would solve my issue. If it does, then that would be ideal.

Comment: It doesn't dump output at you either. You get a list of Diff elements to play with and you get to pull out whatever bits you want from them. See http://www.masnun.com/2012/01/28/fetching-changed-files-diff-between-two-git-commits-in-python.html for example. (I assume that is still valid or ever was, I don't actually know but that looks like what the docs say.)

Comment: @z0d14c Put the code which doesn't work, together with a full description of how it doesn't work, in your question.

Comment: @MattDMo in post now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed or at least on the right track with the following (inspired by someone who deleted their answer... thanks, guy)

```
subprocess.check_output(['git', 'diff', '--name-only', currentBranch + '..' + compBranch])
```

This basically does what I need it to, although if there is a more elegant solution I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way to do this in python.

```
 #Dif two branches, returns list
import git 


def gitDiff(branch1, branch2):
    format = '--name-only'
    commits = []
    g = git.Git('/path/to/git/repo')
    differ = g.diff('%s..%s' % (branch1, branch2), format).split("\n")
    for line in differ:
        if len(line):
            commits.append(line)

    #for commit in commits:
    #    print '*%s' % (commit)
    return commits
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.