# Run pylint for every commit on the modified changes

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, github, pylint

I want to run pylint for every new commit and amend in git. I am a beginner, don't know much about git.

Below are my questions:

1. How to get the modified files using git and jenkins
2. How to perform pylint on the files.

Comment: You could use a pre-commit-hook to pylint the files before it gets committed. Something like: https://git-pylint-commit-hook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: You will have to configure your project in Jenkins, define a webhook and make jenkins run pylint. I advise not to allow Jenkins to do changes in your repository for security reasons and to prevent an endless loop.

Comment: @KlausD. Agreed about the security reasons. My project is already integrated to Jenkins. How to proceed further.

It will be very helpful if you can provide the solution with a sample code

Comment: If you have you project in Jenkins already, then there shouldn't be any problem running one additional command.

Comment: @Klaus D. I want to run pylint from a python file. How can i get the list of files over there ??

Answer (score 1):

> I want to run `pylint` from a python file.
>   How can I get the list of files over there?

Using [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), you can easily [list files in a given commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40567774/6309):

```
commit.stats.files
```

You can then apply `pylint`, using the elements of that list.

Note: to do it without using GitPython, see "[Get a list of changed files between two commits or branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34401578/6309)": compare between `<SHA1>` and `<SHA1>~1`: your commit, and the parent (first ancestor) of your commit.

Comment: Can't we do this without GitPython ?? It will be really helpful, if you can provide a solution without GitPython

Comment: @Shikhar Sure, I have edited my answer accordingly.